# Creating a responsive, full-width chevron with CSS in Wordpress Visual Composer

Tags: html, css, wordpress, sass, row

I am trying to create a responsive, full-width downward chevron underneath a section with CSS, like in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9cxz423/2615/) – in Wordpress Visual Composer.

When I resize the browser window the chevron falls off the page [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnFuI.png), and is not centred in the container [(example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPWnv.png).

I think that `.vc-row` needs to extend to the full-width of the browser, but nothing I have tried seems to work (setting width to `100vw`, `margin` and `padding` to `0` with `!important` etc).

Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="vc-row-container container parent--.chevron-white">
  <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid chevron-white vc_custom_1525861624597 vc_row-has-fill">...
```

**CSS (Sass)**

```
.chevron-black, .chevron-white
  box-sizing: content-box !important
  display: block
  height: 0px
  left: 0 !important
  margin: 0px auto 0 auto
  padding: 0px !important
  position: relative
  text-align: center
  transform: translate(0%, -100%)
  width: 100% !important
  z-index: 999
  .wpb_column
    width: 100% !important
  &:after
    border-style: solid
    border-width: 50px 50px 0 50px
    bottom: -50px
    content: ""
    height: 0
    left: 0
    margin: 0px auto 0 auto
    position: absolute !important
    width: 0
.chevron-black:after
  border-color: $black transparent transparent transparent
.chevron-white:after
  border-color: $white transparent transparent transparent
.parent--.chevron-black, .parent--.chevron-white
  margin: 0 !important
  padding: 0 !important
  width: 100vw !important
```

*Other things to note:*
I am using the Kalium WordPress theme.
`.vc-container` (the visual composer wrapper) is the full width of the browser, `.vc-row-container` is slightly less, and `.vc-row` is slightly less again. As I'm using a Wordpress theme with Visual Composer I can't edit the HTML directly, I can try to override JS and CSS though.